# HOC in react.js docs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React docs in HOC section, there is an example

```
const CommentListWithSubscription = withSubscription(
  CommentList,
  (DataSource) => DataSource.getComments()
);
```

Could you please explain how a function scope works?
They put the second param as an arrow function, in this arrow function we have `DataSource` param and return a result of `DataSource.getComments()`

realization of HOC withSubscription

```
function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, selectData) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        data: selectData(DataSource, props)
      };
    }
...
```

Here they use `selectData` as that function `(DataSource) => DataSource.getComments()`
and fire that function again with `DataSource` param

This moment a bit confused, is it the same `DataSource` that we put in arrow function above or different? and in general how does it work?

Comment: Poor naming choice (variable shadowing)  but they mention in a command (search for the first instance of `DataSource` in the page) `// "DataSource" is some global data source`. BTW, next time, please add the link to the page, not all of us remember the links to React docs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSource` inside the HOC (`withSubscription`) is an existing variable in that scope or global scope, likely obtained via static import or a context.

`DataSource` in the parent (the code that calls the HOC) is just a place-holding parameter. Basically the parent is telling the HOC: "I don't know what data source you're using, just retrieve the comments from it (`DataSource.getComments()`) and use it as your state data".

If the parent wants another HOC instance to use different data (like blog post in the example), it just changes the instruction to `DataSource.getBlogPost()` for that HOC, possibly using some extra parameters passed via the HOC's `props`, like in the example. This pattern makes HOCs as flexible as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

## HOC concept

Any hoc is a normal function which returns a react Component , but with modified props

considering example in react docs :

```
const CommentListWithSubscription = withSubscription(
  CommentList,
  (DataSource) => DataSource.getComments()
);
```

I agree this is definitely not a easiest example to prefer.

consider a simple HOC `withData`

```
const withData = (component, endpoint) => {
  function WrappedComponent(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(endpoint).then((res) => setData(res));
    }, []);

    return (
      <component data={data} {...props} />
    );
  }
  return WrappedComponent;
};

const ComponentWithData = withData(MyCustomComponent, api_endpoint)

function MyCustomComponent (props){
 const { data } = props

// use this data to do whatever 
}
```

when a prop is injected into `<component/>` like `data={[1,2,3]}`, that prop can be accesible through props of resulting component like `props.data`

Answer (score 1):

withSubscription takes 2 arguments: WrappedComponent and selectData.
Notice that in the constructor of withSubscription they set the initial state to equal the result of invoking selectData. selectData is called with 2 arguments: DataSource is the first argument and props is the second.
In this case DataSource is probably some module they imported previously but just didn't show you...

When they wrap a CommentListWithSubscription with "withSubscription", the DataSource there is the data source that is passed in the constructor to initialize the state. They should've named it dataSource instead, that's the correct naming convention.

Hope that helped :)
If don't understand HOC from their docs, just keep searching in other sources. There are hundreds if not thousands of sources that explain that concept. In programming you sometimes need to go through several sources for a concept or and idea to sink in properly. Good luck!